# ¿Cómo guardar un archivo a mysql C# con varbinary?

Tags: mysql, c#

Tengo una duda: ¿Cómo puedo guardar un archivo a mysql C# con varbinary? ¿puedo guardar solo la ruta pero para eso utilizaría `VARCHAR` o también `VARBINARY`?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: A un Nada, porque solo quiero saber  como funciona para la implementación

Comment: Pues es muy sencillo, para guardar un archivo a mysql primero lo serializas y después lo guardas.

Comment: Pero, tengo la duda de que si yo guardo ese archivo en la BD en un campo Varbinary, necesitaría la ruta del archivo y al guardarlo yo podria editar el contenido del documento?... digamos que fue un World que tiene texto, y quiero agregar una imagen tendria que hacer el proceso inverso de serializar y al hacer eso tendria que volverlo a guardar en la BD o el va seguir la ruta? Osea yo podría editar el contenido del doc en el explorador de windows y se vería afectado en la BD eso es lo q quiero

Comment: Obviamente necesitas la ruta del archivo ¿Cómo lees un archivo si no sabes dónde está?